# Camera set to follow path on a bezier circle wobbling in Blender 3.6.2 Mac Studio M1 Max

Tags: camera

My bezier circle is zeroed (with a resolution of 64), my object is zeroed (centred with the circle), the camera is set up to follow path with all the correct settings (follow curve checked, forward axis -x, up axis z).

When animated the camera pans around my object fine... it's just that it wobbles. The objects not wobbling itself, it's actually the circle creating the camera wobble that makes it look like the object wobbles.

I've created a new file to check if it's the file I'm working with, but it happens with the new file too. Am I missing something. Be grateful if anyone could help.

Here's my file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KWaA07YOaH0nv2w_-EybLR0qyD7F20St/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If you give a Damped Track constraint to your camera with the sphere as Target and Track Axis -Z it will fix the problem (but it doesn't answer your question)

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: for me it looks like a bug

Comment: Actually I believe this depends on how exactly Blender is calculating this Bézier curve, but I might be wrong. Just a stupid question: for a simple thing like a rotation around the center, why don't you do exactly that? Rotate the camera around the center? Place an empty in the center, put the camera off the center in the desired distance, parent the camera to the empty and animate the rotation of the empty.

Comment: Thank You moonboots, that solved the issue. I might flag it with Blender as I have the same opinion as Chris. Thank You Gordon, I'm going to give that a try too. Always up for trying new things :) and next time I'll try to be a little less vague Duarte. Cheers guys! Much appreciated.